# How can I remove 'TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str''

Tags: python, client-server

```
import sys
from socket import *

ECHO_PORT = 50000 + 7
BUFSIZE = 1024


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        usage()
    if sys.argv[1] == '-s':
        server()
    elif sys.argv[1] == '-c':
        client()
    else:
        usage()

def usage():
    sys.stdout = sys.stderr
    print('Usage : udpecho -s [port]            (server)')
    print('or:     udpecho -c host [port] <file (client)')
    sys.exit(2)

def server():
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        port = eval(sys.argv[2])
    else:
        port = ECHO_PORT

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)  ## UDP = SOCK_DGRAM, TCP = SOCK_STREAM
    s.bind(('', port))
    print('udp echo server ready')

    while 1:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(BUFSIZE)
        print('server received %r from %r'%(data, addr))
        s.sendto(data, addr)


def client():
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        usage()

    host = sys.argv[2]

    if len(sys.argv) > 3:
        port = eval(sys.argv[3])
    else:
        port = ECHO_PORT

    addr = host, port
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind(('', 0))
    print('udp echo client ready, reading stdin')

    while 1:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        s.sendto(line, addr)

        data, fromaddr = s.recvfrom(BUFSIZE)
        print('client received %r from %r'%(data, fromaddr))
main()
```

I'd like to make client & server program with python.
but this Errors are bothering me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "udp_echo.py", line 98, in <module>
    main()
  File "udp_echo.py", line 32, in main
    client()
  File "udp_echo.py", line 89, in client
    s.sendto(line, addr.encode())
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I'm trying a lot of way to remove this error code, but I don't have any idea.
Some of people told me, this problem cause version of python, but i don't know how can i solve this problem.
How can I remove this error code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s.sendto(line.encode('utf8'), addr)` will turn it into utf8 bytes(probably what you want)

Comment: Unfortunately, It's also followed error code.
'socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'

Comment: This likely means that the host couldnt be found - maybe the host name has a typo? Try with an IP address if you haven't.

Comment: that is a very different error